# Write code that takes a non-empty list of integers from the user, as well as a width

Tags: python, list

So, the problem states that I have to do the following:

Write code that takes a non-empty list of integers from the user, as well as a width. Return a new list where the original list has been converted into a two dimensional list with the specified width, padded with zeroes at the end as needed. You may not use any built-in functions/methods besides len() and .append().

I tried to resolve it and I am still hung up on one line, he is what I have right now:

```
def chop(l1, w):

    list1 = l1
    width = w
    list2 = []
    size = len(list1)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    a = width - size % width

    while i < a:
        list1.append(0)
        i = i + 1
    i = 0
    size = size + a

    height = size // width
    k = 0
    while i < height:
        while j < width:
            list2[i][j] = list1[k]
            k = k + 1
            j = j + 1
        j = 0
        i = i + 1

    return list1
```

But when I try to run the code, I get an error on the line with this code:  `list2[i][j] = list1[k]` giving me an index error.

Comment: You have to return a list of lists (matrix). You have first to establish the number of rows of your matrix (by dividing the initial list length to the given width - and adding one if the 1st is not divisible by the 2nd), then you have to traverse the initial list (in chunks of `width` elements), creating each row and appending it to the matrix. you might need to pad the last row with 0s.

Comment: @CristiFati I updated the code based on your advise and edited the question; I think I am getting really close.

Comment: Because at that point `list2` is an empty list. You can't assign values if a list has no elements. You should use `append` to add new values to the list. In your case for each iteration of `i` you should create an empty list, append the corresponding elements from initial list, when `j` reaches `width`, append this intermediary list to `list2`.

Comment: Could you show me how this looks, @CristiFati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code (note that it could look a lot nicer - and shorter - as *Python* has lots of (powerful) features, but due to the imposed constraints, this is the outcome):

```
def chop(initial_list, width):
    if width <= 0:
        return None
    ret_list = []
    size = len(initial_list)
    height = size // width
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < height:  # Handling the integral (complete/full) rows (if any)
        tmp_list = []
        j = 0
        while j < width:
            tmp_list.append(initial_list[i * width + j])
            j += 1
        ret_list.append(tmp_list)
        i += 1
    remainder = size % width
    tmp_list = []
    if remainder:  # Handling the last(incomplete) row (if any)
        j = i * width
        while j < size:  # Fill the last row with the last elements from initial_list
            tmp_list.append(initial_list[j])
            j += 1
        j = remainder
        while j < width:  # Append 0s till the last row length is equal to width
            tmp_list.append(0)
            j += 1
        ret_list.append(tmp_list)
    elif not height:  # Handle empty list's case
        j = 0
        while j < width:
            tmp_list.append(0)
            j += 1
        ret_list.append(tmp_list)
    return ret_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #  Test our function a little bit...
    l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    print(chop(l1, 2))
    print(chop(l1, 3))
    print(chop(l1, 12))
    print(chop(l1, 1))
    print(chop([], 4))
    print(chop([], 0))
```

And the output is:

> ```
> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 0]]
> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0]]
> [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
> [[0, 0, 0, 0]]
> None
> ```

*@EDIT0*: Added support for empty lists.

Comment: Thank you so much! The only question I have is when I try to test it for  input chop [] 2, I expected '[[0, 0]]', but you got '[]'

Comment: Hmm, you're right. It's an aspect that i missed, you got this result since 0 (length of an empty list), is divisible by any width. I will update the answer shortly.